# What's the point of exporting a new function that calls another instead of the original?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, bundling-and-minification, code-splitting

While exploring (and, for fun, manually decompiling) some JavaScript code bundled with Webpack and split over multiple files, I found that a module does a strange thing: it creates a function, then exports a function that calls the function it created, instead of just exporting the first function.

A simplified, deobfuscated and decompiled version of the code:

```
/*
  __d is the function used for registering modules
  It takes in three arguments:
   - a callback, the module's factory
   - the module's ID
   - the dependency map, an array of the IDs of the module's dependencies (which
     is passed in as the last argument of the factory)
*/
__d(
  function(
    window,
    require,
    import_default,
    import_all,
    module,
    exports,
    dependency_map
  ) {
    // Both are regular functions (not arrow functions)
    function example(arg1, arg2) {
      // ...
      // (note that the function does not use `this`)
      // (although it does import another module via `require`)
      return result;
    }

    // Why not just `exports.run_example = example`?
    exports.run_example = function(arg1, arg2) {
      return example(arg1, arg2);
    }
  },
  // And the other two arguments passed into __d (removed because unimportant)
)
```

Why is this? Isn't just exporting the first function functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this? Isn't just exporting the first function functionally equivalent?

Not quite, but very nearly. With your `example`, it really doesn't make much difference, since as you say it's not using `this` and since it's using two formal non-rest parameters and not using `arguments`. So *basically* equivalent, quibbling aside. :-)

Here are the differences I can see, which probably won't matter to your code:

1. `example` will not be called with the same `this` that `run_example` was called with. It will always get the default `this` (the global `this` in loose mode, `undefined` in strict mode). Your `example` doesn't use `this`, so no relevant difference there.
2. `example` will always get exactly two arguments, regardless of how few or many `run_example` is called with. Since your `example` uses two formal parameters and doesn't use `arguments` or a rest parameter, again, no relevant difference there.
3. On most modern JavaScript engines, `example`'s name (its `name` property and what appears in stack traces) is `example`; `run_example`'s name is `run_example` (yes, really, this was new in the ES2015 spec). So you'll see the difference in stack traces, or if code examines the `name` property of the exported function.
4. Obviously, there's one more function call and thus one more stack frame when called via `run_example`. Your code probably doesn't care.

Here's a snippet illustrating 1-3 three on most modern engines:

```js
"use strict";
function example(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("example:     typeof this? " + typeof this);
    console.log("example:     arguments.length? " + arguments.length);
}
var run_example = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("run_example: typeof this? " + typeof this);
    console.log("run_example: arguments.length? " + arguments.length);
    return example(arg1, arg2);
};

// Call with `this` set to a blank object and no arguments:
run_example.call({});
// Outputs:
// run_example: typeof this? object
// run_example: arguments.length? 0
// example:     typeof this? undefined
// example:     arguments.length? 2

// Call with the default `this` and four arguments:
run_example(1, 2, 3, 4);
// Outputs:
// run_example: typeof this? undefined
// run_example: arguments.length? 4
// example:     typeof this? undefined
// example:     arguments.length? 2

// Function names
console.log("example.name is " + example.name);
console.log("run_example.name is " + run_example.name);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

An example showing the difference with an ES2015+ rest parameter:

```js
"use strict";
function example(...args) {
    console.log("example: args.length? " + args.length);
}
var run_example = function(arg1, arg2) {
    return example(arg1, arg2);
};

// Call with the default `this` and one argument:
run_example(1);
// Outputs:
// example:     args.length? 2

// Whereas calling it directly:
example(1);
// Outputs:
// example: args.length? 1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Despite having upvoted this answer (which, like your other answers, is spot on), it's worth mentioning that OP said *"note that the function does not use `this`"*, which makes #1 not really important, and the fact that JS ignores less/extra arguments kind of does the same for #2. So, genuine question: is there any *relevant* difference?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So, if the function doesn't use `this`, and doesn't access `arguments`, they _are_ equivalent, right?

Comment: @DamianoMagrini - Basically, yes. :-) I've updated the answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - (Thank you!) Assuming `example` also doesn't use a rest parameter to know how many arguments were passed to it, basically no really relevant differences. I've updated the answer to better reflect that (and to call out a couple I missed :-) ).